# How to disable Jquery UI dialog close button's tooltip?

Tags: jquery-ui

How can I disable the tooltip of the Jquery UI dialog's close button?
For example check it here: [jquery ui dialog demo](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)
You should stay with mouse on the close button, and a very annoying Close tooltip will appear.

Thank you!

Comment: May we know why do you want to remove the tooltip?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [api reference](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-closeText)

```
$( "#dialog" ).dialog( "option", "closeText", false );
```

or

```
 $( "#dialog" ).dialog({ closeText: false });
```

see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6a977ou6/)

Comment: Thank you. I found closeText, but in the documentation there is no false option for closeText, just strings.

Comment: You can also use `null` instead of `false`

Comment: I had to use `null` as `false` still displayed the literal "false".

Answer (score 2):

I found above code seems to show "FALSE" as a tooltip in my application.

I solved the issue by changing it to:

$( "#dialog" ).dialog({ closeText: "" });
This will not bring up the tooltip.  Would love to hear if anyone feels I got it incorrectly...

Answer (score 0):

This code will only replace the word "Close" with the word "False" in current versions of JQuery UI.

```
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({ closeText: false });
```

The correct way to handle this is as follows (according to Damien's comment):

```
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({ closeText: null });
```